# Change a mySQL Column datatype from text to timestamp

Tags: mysql

How can I change the datatype of a column from text to timestamp. The current text column is storing dates in the format : '2010-08-15' (yyyy-mm-dd sql format)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`mytable` MODIFY COLUMN `mycol` TIMESTAMP;
```

Using the above command a value such as:

```
'2010-08-15'
```

will change to

```
TIMESTAMP '2010-08-15 00:00:00'
```

[Link to documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this

```
alter table table_name change field_name field_name timestamp;
```

where `table_name` is the name of the table and `field_name` is the name of the field that you wanted alter the type of.